# How to perform a custom JSON deserialization with Jackson that respects a custom annotation?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON into a custom POJO that I am not able to modify.  That POJO has annotations from a different custom internal serialization framework that I'm not able to use.  How can I create a custom deserializer that will respect these annotations?

Here is an example POJO:

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    @Property(name = "id")
    public String id;

    @Property(name = "time_windows")
    @NotNull
    public List<TimeWindow> timeWindows = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class TimeWindow {
        @Property(name = "start")
        public Long start;

        @Property(name = "end")
        public Long end;
    }
}
```

So in this case, the deserializer would look for fields in the JSON that correspond to the `Property` annotations, and use the value in that annotation to decide what field to grab.  If a property *doesn't* have the `Property` annotation, it should be ignored.

I have been going through the Jackson docs but haven't been able to find exactly what I need.  Is this a place where an `AnnotationIntrospector` would be useful?  Or possibly a `ContextualDeserializer`?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update: I tried implementing the advice in the comments, but without success.**

Here is my initial implementation of the introspector:

```kotlin
class CustomAnnotationInspector : JacksonAnnotationIntrospector () {
    override fun hasIgnoreMarker(m: AnnotatedMember?): Boolean {
        val property = m?.getAnnotation(Property::class.java)
        return property == null
    }

    override fun findNameForDeserialization(a: Annotated?): PropertyName {
        val property = a?.getAnnotation(Property::class.java)
        return if (property == null) {
            super.findNameForDeserialization(a)
        } else {
            PropertyName(property.name)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where I actually use it:

```kotlin
// Create an empty instance of the request object.
val paramInstance = nonPathParams?.type?.getDeclaredConstructor()?.newInstance()

// Create new object mapper that will write values from
// JSON into the empty object.
val mapper = ObjectMapper()

// Tells the mapper to respect custom annotations.
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(CustomAnnotationInspector())

// Write the contents of the request body into the StringWriter
// (this is required for the mapper.writeValue method
val sw = StringWriter()
sw.write(context.bodyAsString)

// Deserialize the contents of the StringWriter
// into the empty POJO.
mapper.writeValue(sw, paramInstance)
```

Unfortunately it seems that `findNameForDeserialization` is never called, and none of the JSON values are written into `paramInstance`.  Can anybody spot where I'm going wrong?

Thank you!

---

**Update 2: I changed the code slightly, I'm now able to identify the property names but Jackson is failing to create an instance of the object.**

Here's my new code:

```kotlin
val mapper = ObjectMapper()

// Tells the mapper to respect CoreNg annotations.
val introspector = CustomAnnotationInspector()
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector)

val paramInstance = mapper.readValue(context.bodyAsString,nonPathParams?.type)
```

My breakpoints in the custom annotation introspector are getting hit.  But I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `app.employee.api.employee.BOUpsertEmployeeRequest` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Here is the POJO I'm trying to deserialize:

```java
public class BOUpsertEmployeeRequest {
    public BOUpsertEmployeeRequest () { }

    @NotNull
    @Property(name = "xref_code")
    public String xrefCode;

    @Property(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Property(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Property(name = "email_address")
    public String emailAddress;

    @Property(name = "phone")
    public String phone;

    @Property(name = "address")
    public List<String> address;

    @Property(name = "employment_status")
    public String employmentStatus;

    @Property(name = "pay_type")
    public String payType;

    @Property(name = "position")
    public String position;

    @Property(name = "skills")
    public List<String> skills;

    @Property(name = "gender")
    public String gender;
}
```

As far as I can tell it has a default constructor.  Anybody have any idea what the problem is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method [hasIgnoreMarker](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.html#hasIgnoreMarker-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember-) is called not only for *fields*, but also for the *constructor*, including the virtual one:

> Method called to check whether given property is marked to be ignored. This is used to determine whether to ignore properties, on per-property basis, usually combining annotations from multiple accessors (getters, setters, fields, constructor parameters).

In this case you should ignore only *fields*, that are not marked properly:

```java
static class CustomAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a) {
        Property property = a.getAnnotation(Property.class);
        if (property == null) {
            return PropertyName.USE_DEFAULT;
        } else {
            return PropertyName.construct(property.name());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        return m instanceof AnnotatedField
                && m.getAnnotation(Property.class) == null;
    }
}
```

---

**Example:**

```java
class Pojo {
//    @Property(name = "id")
    Integer id;
//    @Property(name = "number")
    Integer number;
    @Property(name = "assure")
    Boolean assure;
    @Property(name = "person")
    Map<String, String> person;
}
```

```java
String json =
        "{\"id\" : 1, \"number\" : 12345, \"assure\" : true," +
        " \"person\" : {\"name\" : \"John\", \"age\" : 23}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomAnnotationIntrospector());
Pojo pojo = mapper.readValue(json, Pojo.class);

System.out.println(pojo);
```

```
Pojo{id=null, number=null, assure=true, person={name=John, age=23}}
```

---

**Note:** Custom `Property` annotation should have [RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) (same as [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation):

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Property {
    String name();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.
I had to replace `return PropertyName.USE_DEFAULT;` with `return super.findNameForDeserialization(a);`.

Jackson already has an implementation of `findNameForDeserialization` that is important to fallback to.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a different approach:

In the runtime, with the bytecode instrumentation library [Byte Buddy](https://bytebuddy.net/) and its Java agent, re-annotate the fields with the proper Jackson Annotations. Simply implement the logic via reflection. See the following example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType.Builder;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType.Builder.FieldDefinition.Valuable;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassReloadingStrategy;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyJsonIgnore {
}
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyJsonProperty {
  String name();
}
```

```java
public class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    ClassReloadingStrategy classReloadingStrategy = ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent();
    ByteBuddy byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy();
    AnnotationDescription jsonIgnoreDesc =
        AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(JsonIgnore.class).build();

    Builder<Person> personBuilder = byteBuddy.redefine(Person.class);

    for (Field declaredField : Person.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
      Valuable<Person> field = personBuilder.field(ElementMatchers.named(declaredField.getName()));

      MyJsonProperty myJsonProperty = declaredField.getAnnotation(MyJsonProperty.class);
      if (myJsonProperty != null) {
        AnnotationDescription jsonPropertyDesc =
            AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(JsonProperty.class)
                .define("value", myJsonProperty.name())
                .build();
        personBuilder = field.annotateField(jsonPropertyDesc);
      }

      MyJsonIgnore myJsonIgnore = declaredField.getAnnotation(MyJsonIgnore.class);
      if (myJsonIgnore != null) {
        personBuilder = field.annotateField(jsonIgnoreDesc);
      }
    }

    personBuilder.make().load(Sample.class.getClassLoader(), classReloadingStrategy);

    Person person = new Person("Utku", "Ozdemir", "Berlin");
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
  }
}
```

```java
class Person {
  @MyJsonProperty(name = "FIRST")
  private String firstName;

  @MyJsonProperty(name = "LAST")
  private String lastName;

  @MyJsonIgnore private String city;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String city) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.city = city;
  }
}
```

In the example above, I

- create `MyJsonProperty` and `MyJsonIgnore` annotations and a `Person` class for the demonstration purpose
- instrument the current Java process with the Byte buddy agent
- create a bytebuddy builder to redefine the `Person` class
- loop over the fields of the `Person` class and check for these annotations
- add an additional annotation to each of those fields (on the builder), Jackson's `JsonProperty` (with the correct field name mapping) and `JsonIgnore`.
- after being done with the fields, make the new class bytecode and load it to the current classloader using the byte buddy agent's class reloading mechanism
- write a person object to the stdout.

It prints, as expected:

```
{"FIRST":"Utku","LAST":"Ozdemir"}
```

(the field `city` is ignored)

This solution might feel like an overkill, but on the other side, it is pretty generic solution - with a few changes in the logic, you could handle all the 3rd party classes (which you are not able to modify) instead of handling them case by case.