# Jackson custom annotation for field level deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

Attempting to deserialize input Json having nested fields and different field names. Hoping for a way to deserilize using JsonPointer espression (because it allows path lookup).

Several approaches tried but none of them worked so far.

- Using AnnotationIntrospector = introspector gets invoked which returns a custom deserializer from overridden findDeserializer(). However, custom JsonDeserialiser.deserialize() never invoked on mapper.readValue()
- Using ContextualDeserilizer = it gets invoked which returns a custom deserializer. However, custom JsonDeserialiser.deserialize() never invoked on mapper.readValue()

The custom deserialiser only invoked when it is declared on the class (not on field).

References: Most of them are related to serialization, however the use case is for deserialization.

[Jackson custom annotation for custom value serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342097/jackson-custom-annotation-for-custom-value-serialization)

[Customize Jackson ObjectMapper to Read custom Annotation and mask fields annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965201/customize-jackson-objectmapper-to-read-custom-annotation-and-mask-fields-annotat)

[How to perform a custom JSON deserialization with Jackson that respects a custom annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362602/how-to-perform-a-custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson-that-respects-a-custom)

[Jackson, custom "writer" for annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120278/jackson-custom-writer-for-annotation?newreg=b53a8ee8da3046f6be22db82e9e34a55)

https://bsideup.github.io/posts/custom_jackson_annotations/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper

https://github.com/arthureffting/custom-serialization-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/globalserialization/demo/serialization/MyCustomSerializer.java

Following are classes:
Using jackson with lombok

```java
// custom annotation

@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface JsonPointerProperty {

    String value();
}

// Person POJO

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}

// Address POJO

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Address {

// using custom annotation
    @JsonPointerProperty("/requestModel/streetName")
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String postcode;
}
```

```java
// introspector 

public class JsonPointerPropertyIntrospector
        extends NopAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Object findDeserializer(Annotated am) {

        final JsonPointerProperty jsonPointerProperty = am.getAnnotation(JsonPointerProperty.class);
        if (jsonPointerProperty != null) {
            return new JsonPointerPropertyDeserializer(
                    jsonPointerProperty.value(),
                    am.getType().getRawClass()
            );
        }

        return super.findDeserializer(am);
    }
}

// custom deserializer
public class JsonPointerPropertyDeserializer
        extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    private final String jsonPath;
    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public JsonPointerPropertyDeserializer() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public JsonPointerPropertyDeserializer(String jsonPath,
                                           Class<?> clazz) {
        this.jsonPath = jsonPath;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx)
            throws IOException, JacksonException {

        // not reaching here
        JsonNode jsonNode = parser.readValueAs(JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode at = jsonNode.at(jsonPath);

        String value = ctx.readTreeAsValue(jsonNode, String.class);

        System.out.println(value);

        return null;
    }
}
```

The actual data contains nested level objects having different field names.

```java
// Unit test

class PersonTest {
    String json;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws IOException {
        json = "{ 'address': { 'requestModel': { 'streetName': 'some street', 'cityName': 'some city' }}}"
                .replace(
                "'",
                "\""
        );
    }

    @Test
    void testPerson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JsonPointerPropertyIntrospector());

        final Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);

        assertEquals("some street", person.getAddress().getStreet(), "Street mismatch");
    }
}
```

There is some error parsing `requestModel` which I need to figure out (maybe use JsonSetter or JsonProperty?), but I was hoping it would at least reach to custom deserializer.

Appreciate your time and any suggestions.